# Cannot connect to Tryton database

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, tryton

After installing the standard Tryton packages in Ubuntu 12.04, I can start the client and create a new database. But the client refuses to connect to the database. It will display the locally created databases, but will fail to add the localhost profile.

If I try to add a new profile, the client will show the installed databases, but on clicking ok will fail silently back to the start screen, without adding the new profile.

New profile setting was:

```
Hostname: localhost
Port: 8000
Database: [Correctly displays the list of created Dbs]
Username: [I've tried everything from tryton, admin, test to root]
```

I have also tried to connect directly in the Tryton client without adding a new profile, then it will always yield "Bad user or password", no matter how exact I re-enter the `tryton` user with his password, or any other user (admin, root) for that matter.

I have followed the procedure in the documentation (Readme.debian: adding database user in **/etc/trytond.conf** and so forth, have registered tryton user with postgres and in trytond.conf).

Do I need to be logged in as `tryton` on Remote Desktop maybe?
The client was started on the Ubuntu desktop via Remote Desktop, logged in as root.
Tried to log in as `tryton`, too. That will get to the desktop, but somehow not show the Terminal window. Hence I can't start the Tryton client. Terminal will blink for a second and then vanish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a dabatase from the tryton client it ask you the admin password. You must enter with the 'admin' username and with the admin password you used on the database creation step.

Once you enter the system you will see and step to create additional User. You can skip it if you want, as they can be created at any time from Administration -> Users -> Users menú.

You must never use the passwords entered on etc/trytond.conf as this credentials are used from the tryton server to conect to the database. User logins are managed by tryton server.

Comment: Hm, indeed, I now just entered "admin" as the standard password in all three fields in the "Create database" dialog and it worked. Seems somehow counterintuitive to me, but never mind. Thank you very much indeed! (It's just that there are no modules installed now, but I guess I can remedy that with   sudo apt-get install tryton-server tryton-modules-all. I've made so many attempts at this by now on different machines that it's hard to recall what got installed where ;-)

Comment: Yes you can install tryton-modules-all to get all the official modules. Can I ask you which debian/ubntu version are using? Normally, apt-get reports are outdated, so I will recomend you using pip & virtualenv to get newer tryton versions.